# Como fazer uma query sql no MoongoDb com php?

Tags: php, sql, mongodb

Como faço a seguinte query sql no mongo?

```
select * from myDB WHERE nm_pesquisa LIKE "%SAO%" AND tp_m = "A" OR tp_m = "H";
```

Tentei da seguinte forma mas sem sucesso:

```
$query = [
    'nm_pesquisa' => ['$regex' => MDB::Regex($nm)],
    'tp_m' => "A",
    '$or' => [['tp_m' => "A"]]
];
```

Comment: Acho que é assim: `db.inventory.find( {
    'nm_pesquisa' => ['$regex' => MDB::Regex($nm)],
     $or: [ { tp_m: "A"}, { tp_m: "H"}]
} )`, procurei aqui: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Comment: @Don'tPanic sem sucesso ele ignora o { tp_m: "H"}

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente (mesmo não sendo o seu problema atual) a tua query esta "errada":

```
select * from myDB WHERE nm_pesquisa LIKE "%SAO%" AND tp_m = "A" OR tp_m = "H";
```

Você tem um `OR` junto a um `AND`, em mysql pode até funcionar, mas com certeza me parece bem errado ou traria talvez algum resultado inesperado ou faltando algum resultado, de qualquer forma creio que na verdade seria isto o esperado:

```
select * from myDB WHERE nm_pesquisa LIKE "%SAO%" AND (tp_m = "A" OR tp_m = "H");
```

Um detalhe o `FROM` não seleciona o banco, talvez você já saiba, ele seleciona a tabela, é claro que dá pra selecionar uma tabela em um banco especifico, mas ainda sim é a tabela, só para explicar, é que `myDB` ali talvez não faça sentido, de qualquer forma presumo que seja um erro de digitação.

Agora vamos ao `OR` e `AND` no MongoDB, basicamente teria que usar `$or` para resolver e aplicar ambas condições de `OR` do `SELECT` dentro dele, a sua query provavelmente ficar assim:

> Nota: mantive o `myDB`, mas se trata do documento
>
> Nota: usei `/.*SAO.*/` que é a regex

```
db.myDB.find({
   "nm_pesquisa": { $regex: /.*SAO.*/ },
   $or: [
      {"tp_m": "A"}, {"tp_m": "H"}
   ]
})
```

Com as libs nativas do PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php, creio que deve ficar assim:

```
 $regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('.*SAO.*');
```

Se for case-insensitive seria assim:

```
$regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('.*SAO.*', 'i');
```

Então depois é só passar o `$regex` assim no filter e as condições do `OR` para `tp_m` são dentro `$or => [...]`

```
$filter = [
    'nm_pesquisa' => $regex,
    '$or' => [
         [ 'tp_m' => 'A' ], [ 'tp_m' => 'H' ]
    ]
];
```

> Se eu tiver errado algo me avise, nunca trabalhei com mongoDB, o que respondi acima foi baseado na documentação, então posso ter entendido algo errado

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta mas já tentei como você descreveu e não funcionou. Sobre o myDB que você questionou e o nome do banco de dados de teste que utilizo no servidor. Não e um nome agradável para um banco hahah. Mas e o que tem. mas também houve um erro de digitação a query que informei na pergunta e um resumo da que utilizo, mas e a parte do OR que estou enfrentando problema. O mongoDB e meio chato para fazer query muito complexas além dele perder o índice por causa do uso de regEx quando o termo informado e muito grande

Comment: @usuario o `db.myDB.find` funcionou no terminal/cmd?

Comment: Também não funcionou. Ele ignora o tp_m = "H"

Comment: @usuario a sua condição é (independente de código) deve retornar qual destas duas (1. ou 2.)? ===> **1.** "`nm_pesquisa` e `tp_m = A`" ou "`nm_pesquisa` e `tp_m = H`" / **2.** "`nm_pesquisa` e `tp_m = A`" ou apenas "`tp_m = H`" ... espero que de para entender a logica

Comment: Sim. Já entendi a lógica. No meu caso tem dados iguais no banco que so muda o tp_m nao se era para retornar todos?

Comment: No mysql retorno todos os dados que preciso. No mongo não